# Ms sql server or mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I am making a website in asp.net. 
So my question is, which database is the best for my site.
ms sql server or mysql. 
please explain why i should choose one for another.
no specific needs just want to know the cons and pros of mysql and ms sql

Comment: Too little information. Neither database is best for everything, so you have to descrive your specific needs.

Comment: no specific needs just want to know the cons and pros of mysql and ms sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,
You're using .NET, so, if You use MS SQL Server You can have more features and facilities to implement things. You can have more tools, optmized environment, etc...

You need to evaluate some things:
- Your host have MS SQL Srvr databases? for same price?
- You can expend more to have it?

In my opinion, for .NET, MS SQL is the first choice...